# What the following code prints / with arrays, pointers etc

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, operators, sizeof

I have problem solving this problem, so if anyne had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

```
short y[2][3]={{0123},{0x12345}},*p=y[1];
printf("01:%x\n", y);
printf("02:%x\n", p);
printf("03:%x\n", sizeof(y));
printf("04:%x\n", sizeof(y[0]));
printf("05:%x\n", sizeof(&y[0]));
printf("06:%x\n", sizeof(*p));
printf("07:%x\n", sizeof(p++));
printf("08:%x\n", *p++);
printf("09:%x\n", *p);
return 0;
```

Can anyone explain to me why the printout is like this?

```
01:61ff10
02:61ff16
03:c
04:6
05:4
06:2
07:4
08:2345
09:0
```

My opinion:

```
01:Prints the address where the array y begins.
02:Prints the address of the pointer, which points to the second element of the array. Since we have 2 * 3 elements that are of type short, each subsequent element of the zero element will increase by 6.
03:Since we have 2 * 3 elements, which is equal to 6, but the elements of the type are short, so it will print hexadecimal c
04:the number of elements in the zero position is 3, but they are of the short type, so it prints 6
05:prints the sizeof addresses of the first element of the array which is 4
06:I don't know why it prints 2 here
07:Prints the sizeof of the pointer address which is 4, it will increase after printing
08:I do not understand
09:I do not understand
```

Can anyone explain why it prints like this?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Jabberwocky How will that explain *why* it produces the output. They already know what the output is.

Comment: `0x12345` isn't likely a valid initializer for a short so that part is wrong. `0123` is an _octal number_ which probably doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: regarding: `printf("08:%x\n", *p++);`  this expression `*p++` has a precedence  problem,, suggest: `(*p)++`

Comment: regarding: `{0123}`  this is an octal number,  is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

OK, let's see:

- #01: The address of `y`.
- #02: The value of `p`, which holds the address of `y[1]`, which is the second element of type `short[3]`. The size of a `short` is apparently 2 on your system, so the offset to #01 is 6.
- #03: The size of the array `y`, `2 * 3 * sizeof (short)` give 12, in hex `c`.
- #04: The size of the element `y[0]`, which is of type `short[3]`. 6, as you found.
- #05: The size of the address of `y[0]`, and apparently the size of an address is 4 on your system.
- #06: The size of the object that `p` points to. This is a `short`, so 2.
- #07: The size of the expression `p++`, which is an address, so 4. And no, `p` is not incremented, since the expression is not evaluated.
- #08: The value of the object that `p` points to, which is `y[1][0]`. Since the initializing value of `0x12345` is an `int` too big to be stored in a `short`, it is truncated to `0x2345`. After reading the value, `p` is incremented.
- #09: The element `p` points to, which is `y[1][1]`. It was initialized to 0.

***Notes:***

*You should have got warnings from your compiler:*

- *The mentioned initializer is truncated.*
- *The format for pointers/addresses is `%p`.*
- *The type of the result of `sizeof` might not match the format `%x`.*

*You should take warnings seriously, they are always a hint that you most probably made an error.*

Answer (score 1):

N6) Sizeof(*p) is size of datatype pointed by p. p is pointer to short: so 2 bytes.

N8) p is pointer to short, it`s pointing to array element y[1][0].
y[1] and y[1][0] have the same memory address.

All array elements are short, 0x12345 truncates to 0x2345 upon array initialisation. So output is 2345.
Also, p++ increases pointer value to point to next short y[1][1].

N9) Because of p++ in step N8, pointer now points to y[1][1], which was initialised to 0 (by default, because init value not provided) - output is 0.